# trying to run mvn install on the xgboost directory, error

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, xgboost

I aim at getting xgboost for pyspark installed.

Trying to have mvn installing xgboost package (including xgboost4j-spark) via jvm-packages pom as explained here: https://medium.com/@bogdan.cojocar/how-to-make-xgboost-available-in-the-spark-notebook-de14e425c948

I am stuck at mvn install because of the following error.

[command error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEB9s.png)

Please help, huge headache here. My system is windows 64 bit

[directory structure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTXao.png)

[directory structure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6x3lb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

1. check java -version and javac -version: they have to be consistent, otherwise problem with that
2. check PATH_JAVA pointing at JDK consistently
3. upgrade scala-maven-plugin: https://github.com/davidB/scala-maven-plugin (3.3.3)